# React-Native-SVG "No Stop in Gradient"

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

**Description**

React-Native-Svg have issue for certain svg icon with gradient.

### Platform

1. IOS 13.4
2. Android 6 and above
3. react-native-svg - v12.1.0

### Issue

1. Here is the link to the svg file https://svgshare.com/i/L5A.svg
2. I export using SvgCss and the results is like below
3. I use react-native-svg-transformer - v0.14.3 show the same results also

[image: How it shows]
.

it shows like this

[image: This is how it should show]
.

By right need to show like this

Comment: There are two solutions in this GitHub issue: 1) open the file in a different editor and re-save it; 2) validate the file and make changes.
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/1292

Comment: Neither of those actually worked for me, though while editing the file, I found a `<linearGradient />` tag that had no stops defined. It did not show as a validation error. But deleting it did solve my issue and didn't change the image in any way I could perceive.